# Scala style with Futures

Tags: scala, asynchronous

Looking for the best way to write a chain of functions that need to run async one after the other. Given these two options:

**Option 1**

```
def operation1(): Unit = {...}
def operation2(): Unit = {...}

def foo(): Future[Unit] = 
  Future { 
    operation1()
    operation2() 
  } onComplete {case _ => println("done!")}
```

**Option 2**

```
def operation1(): Future[Unit] = {...}
def operation2(): Future[Unit] = {...}

def foo(): Future[Unit] = {
  operation1()
    .flatMap {case _ => operation2() }
    .onComplete {case _ => println("done!")}
}
```

1. Are there any advantages/disadvantages of one over the other?
2. I believe that the Option 1 will run the two functions on the same background thread. Is that also the case for the Option 2?
3. Are there any good practices for this?

Another question, given this function:

```
def foo: Future[A]
```

if I want to cast the result to unit, is this the best way to do it:

```
foo map { _ => () }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The potential advantage of **Option 1** over **Option 2** is that, it guarantees `operation2` will run right after `operation1` - if it didn't fail with an exception - whereas, in **Option 2**, you might have exhausted your thread pool available threads when the `flatMap` is to be done.

Yes, **Option1** will run the operations in the same thread for sure. **Option 2** will try to run them in two threads as long as there are enough of them available.

```
flatMap[S](f: (T) ⇒ Future[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S]
```

You did have to declare an implicit execution context, or import it: That determines which pool you are using. If you imported the default `global` executor then your pool is a fork join based one with - by default - as many threads as cores you machine has.

**The first option is like having a thread running both operations, one after the another whereas the second option runs the first operation in a thread and then tries to get another thread from your ExecutionContext to run the second operation.**

The best practice is to use what you need:

*Do you want to make sure that `operation2` run in a context where no more threads are available in the execution context?* If the answer is yes, then use **Option1**. Otherwise, you can use *Option2*

In relation to your last question: What you're doing in your proposed snippet is not casting, your are mapping a function which provides an `Unit` value for any value of type `A`.  The effect is that you get a future of type `Unit` which is useful to check its completion state. That is the best way to get what you seem to want.

Be aware, however, of the fact that, as well as with `flatMap`, the execution of that "transformation function" will be run in a different thread provided by the implicit executor in your context. That is why `map` has an implicit parameter `executor` too:

```
def map[S](f: (T) ⇒ S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S]
```